# Numbering side-by-side equations or inline equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering, inline

I am trying to produce a two-column table of math equations, where each cell contains its own left-justified, numbered equation.

I tried using `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` inside the tabular environment, or inside a description list with `multicols`, and I can get the numbering, but not the left-justification.

I thought about using inline math mode in the table, but how do I get those equations to be numbered? Is there a little `\numberthisequation` command I can include in the ( inline-math ) commands?

I suppose, I could use two `\minipages` side by side, but I was hoping for something a little more straightforward.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [parallel package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel)? I don't use LaTeX to typeset mathematics so I can't say for certain this will meet your needs, so I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: @Scribblemacher: You don't use LaTeX to typeset mathematics? I'm confused...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a little workaround to get what you need:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}p{8cm}}

{\begin{align}
&\alpha = \beta + \gamma \\
&c = 20x^2 + 5x - 10
\end{align}}
&
{\begin{align}
&x_f = x_0 + v_0t \\
&\mu = 10 * \epsilon
\end{align} }

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

The key concepts with this example are:

- You use tabular with columns defined by `p{dim}`.
- The tabular has only one row.
- For every cell of the tabular, you have an array of equations (`align`), whose equations are defined at the right of the `&`, so they get aligned to the left.
- *Very important trick*: to compile, you have to enclose every `align` environment inside `{}`, so that the `&` doesn't collide with those of the `tabular`.

One flaw this approach has: as every `align` environment is independent from the others, if one of the equations has more height, then they will look misaligned vertically. Try writing the

```
\frac{at^2}{2}
```

to the right of the third equation.

Comment: What if I want to place the numbering before each item?

Answer (score 2):

To left-align equations globally, use the `fleqn` option when loading `amsmath`. To left-align equations for only part of the document, you could load the `nccmath` package and use its `fleqn` environment. But then you'd still have the equations in actual `equation` environments, which creates vertical spacing problems.

It seems pretty simple to make your own inline equation tags, though, so try this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\teqtag}{\hfill\stepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2 in}@{\hspace{0.25 in}}p{2 in}}
  $\alpha=\beta+\gamma$\teqtag & $c=20x^2+5x-10$\teqtag   \\
  $\alpha=\frac{10x}{\int y\,dx}+\gamma$\teqtag & $c=20x^2+5x-10$\teqtag\\
  $x_f=x_0+v_0 t$\teqtag       & $\mu=10*\epsilon$\teqtag
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Or to number the equations column-first (and put the tag on the left while we're at it):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcommand{\lteqtag}{\stepcounter{lequation}(\thelequation)\ }
\newcommand{\rteqtag}{\stepcounter{requation}(\therequation)\ }
\newenvironment{spliteqs}%
  {\newcounter{lequation}%
  \newcounter{requation}%
  \setcounter{lequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{requation}{\value{equation}}%
  \addtocounter{requation}{3}}% number of left-column equations
  {\setcounter{equation}{\value{requation}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{spliteqs}
\begin{tabular}{p{2 in}@{\hspace{0.25 in}}p{2 in}}
  \lteqtag$\alpha=\beta+\gamma$ & \rteqtag$c=20x^2+5x-10$   \\
  \lteqtag$\alpha=\frac{10x}{\int y\,dx}+\gamma$\ & \rteqtag$c=20x^2+5x-10$\\
  \lteqtag$x_f=x_0+v_0 t$       & \rteqtag$\mu=10*\epsilon$
\end{tabular}
\end{spliteqs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to add a new answer, without providing a new one. I just wanted to comment the code supplied by rdhs is indeed simple and effective. But I think that, in order to be complete, it needs to define a way to label the equation too. Perhaps if some moderator could edit this and set it as a response to rdhs answer, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I'm not sure if I understand your question... does this meet your needs?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $a+b$
\item $c+d$ 
\item $e+f$
\columnbreak
\item $1+2$
\item $3+4$
\item $5+6$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Here is what this looks like:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Nicolas' output looks like what I need.  I'm still hoping for a simpler method.