# How do I get rid of this line spacing after multicols?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, multicol

How do I get rid of the extra spacing after `multicols`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \noindent    \[ a = b \]
        \columnbreak \[ a = b \]
    \end{multicols}
    \noindent \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you want to group the equations by column without using `multicols`, you could use `p{}` columns within a `tabular`, as in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35961/9092). But that still leaves a lot of vertical space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for typesetting math expression `multicols` are not the best choice. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[ a = b \qquad a = b \]
  \noindent \lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you just have two single expression to go next to each other `\qquad` inserts just some whitespace to push them apart. If you have more places were you want to typeset math you might want to look at the `align` environment. Have a look at [mathmode](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) for more examples.

Comment: Whoa... what is this magic... +1 thanks a bunch. :) What's the difference between `qquad` and `columnbreak` though?

Comment: The trouble with `align` is that it doesn't do what I want -- I want to have three columns of equations, but the equations are grouped *vertically*, not horizontally. I don't necessarily even have the same number of rows in every column... how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Mehrdad If you take a look at the `mathmode` pdf you will find plenty of examples with multiple columns. You just use `&&` to separate the different columns and end the line with `\\ ` to begin a new row. If you have equations you can write `a&=b&` to align the equations by the `=` sign.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that doing so *groups by row*, not by column. So it's not flexible -- when I later decide to remove a cell, I will have to change the *entire* table just to shift up the elements under it.

Comment: @Mehrdad I am afraid I don't know what you mean by “group by row”. `align` environments allow math to be typeset in a grid like fashion. And yes if you remove one from the middle, it is troublesome to move the ones below up. But that is taken care of by a good editor with a column edit mode, as well as alinging the source so it can be cut and pasted easily.