# Equations side-by-side, both numbers on the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering

How can I typeset two equations side-by-side but get both equation numbers printed on the right?

```
          a = b            c = d      (1, 2)
```

I need to reference both equations individually in the text.

I am aware of the questions asked by [SuperElectric](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32701/side-by-side-equations-with-equation-numbers-for-each) and [HTG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35945/numbering-side-by-side-equations-or-inline-equations), but they are not looking for both numbers to appear on the right-hand side of the page.

Comment: Have you considered manual numbering? It might be the easiest solution, if the amount of equations in the document is not to large.

Comment: Are you sure that your readers will understand clearly what's intended when you reference equation 2? Use two lines and no doubt will arise.

Comment: @Mythio Is there a way to do that without loosing the ability to use `\label{}` and `\ref{}`?

Comment: @egreg I think this is an important consideration, but in my case it should be fairly clear and I need to get as much information on each page as possible :)

Comment: @severin I have to agree with egreg though. But if the space is really that important, I would strongly suggest to follow the answer as given in the question by `SuperElectric`. At the very least, it is clear than which equation you will be referring too. As for the `\label{}`, if you are doing manual numbering, it doesn't make much sense to use automated labels/references...

Comment: @Mythio I'd avoid those solutions where the equation number appears in the midde of the column.

Comment: @egreg; Why? if placing them below each other is not an option, would you prefer the format `severin` is looking for? or something different entirely?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Save the meaning of `\label` (after loading `hyperref`, if you do) and use `equation*` together with `\tag`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % optional

\AtBeginDocument{\let\latexlabel\label}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\refstepcounter{equation}\latexlabel{firsthalf}
\refstepcounter{equation}\latexlabel{secondhalf}
a=b\qquad c=d
\tag{\ref*{firsthalf}, \ref*{secondhalf}}
\end{equation*}

Another
\begin{equation}
e=f
\end{equation}

\ref{firsthalf} and \ref{secondhalf}
\end{document}
```

If you don't use `hyperref`, then use simply `\ref` and not `\ref*` (which is meant to avoid creating a spurious link).

[image]

Comment: wouldn't you want the usual formatting of `\eqref`, with parentheses, and always upright?  (i haven't tried it, but it wouldn't be hard to emulate manually if `\eqref` itself doesn't work.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Using `\tag` ensures that the multiple equation number is upright and parenthesized. Of course for the references in text it's better to use `\eqref`.

Comment: it was the references in text that i was referring to, not the numbers on the display equations.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I see; I can confirm that `\eqref` works without problems in the example.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I ended up using it because it seems the most clean to me. And +1 for also taking care of `hyperref`. I guess many people are using that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice work-around! I'm having trouble getting it to work properly with `mathtools`' feature `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}`. It's fine that your construct is not recognised by `showonlyrefs=true` - I can switch it off before and on after the equation in question. However, the first labelled equation _after_ that isn't referenced correctly (even though the equation number is fine). If you happen to know what's causing this, I'd be very grateful for a fix.

Comment: @Axel Maybe a new question with a minimal example can lead at a solution.

Answer (score 9):

The following manual solution is based on package `amsmath` that takes care that the equation numbers can be referenced:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\stepeqlabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \label{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\theequationadd}[1]{%
  \the\numexpr\value{equation}+(#1)\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Two equations \eqref{eq:first} and \eqref{eq:second} in one line:
  \stepeqlabel{eq:first}
  \begin{align}
    a&=b & c&=d
    \tag{\theequation, \theequationadd{1}}
  \end{align}
  \stepeqlabel{eq:second}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\tag` is used to overwrite the normal equation number.
- If `\tag` is used, the equation number is not updated. Therefore the equation counter is incremented *before* the equation system.
- `align` (`amsmath`) thinks, there is only one equation number in the equation system. Therefore the equation counter is incremented after the system to match the second equation number. also the label is placed here.
- If a `\label` is not needed, replace `\stepeqlabel{...}` by `\stepcounter{equation}`.
- `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` comes from the LaTeX kernel to avoid duplicate spaces for `\label` and similar commands `\index`.
- If the equation number is formatted differently than plain arabic numbers, then `\theequationadd` can be adopted.

Comment: When I use the `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` command of the `amsmath` package to add the `1.` (if it's the first section) before the number of the equation in its caption, it is added only to the first of the two captions. Is it possible to extend it over to the second caption too?

Comment: @EdoardoSerra Macro `\theequationadd` simulates the next equation number. Here, the section number also needs to be added, e.g. `\newcommand*{\theequationadd}{\thesection.\the\numexpr\value{equation}+(#1)\relax}`.