# Problem with side by side equation tag and custom tag style

Tags: errors, equations, hyperref, mathtools, tags

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\latexlabel\label}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\refstepcounter{equation}\latexlabel{a}
\refstepcounter{equation}\latexlabel{c}
\refstepcounter{equation}\latexlabel{e}
a=b\quad c=d\quad e=f 
\tag{\ref*{a},$,$ \ref*{c},$,$ \ref*{e}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it doesn't show the third tag and gives me two errors:

- `paragraph ended before @firstoffive was complete`
- `argument of @firstoffive has an extra }`

I think the problems are due to the `hyperref` package because by removing it and substituting `\tag*` with `\tag` it doesn't give me any error whatsoever. In addition, when using `hyperref` I've to manually insert the commas in a math environment in order for them to be shown.

What are those errors? How can I get rid of them and have the file to compile correctly?

Thank you for your time, it is very appreciated.

Edit:

For more clarity, this is what the code erringly compiles to:

[image]

This is how I want it to compile, and how correctly compiles without using the `hyperref` package:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the two `$,$` items in the argument of `\tag`? And what are you trying to achieve by using `\latexlabel` rather than `\label` directly?

Comment: @Mico I've to insert manually the commas in a math environment because otherwise, for some obscure reason, it doesn't plot the commas between the tag numbers.

I've not written the code myself, I took it from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120670/equations-side-by-side-both-numbers-on-the-right

Comment: @Mico question edited, now it should be more clear what is asked, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the code to compile correctly, `\AtBeginDocument{\let\latexlabel\label}` has to be loaded after the `hyperref` package. Doing so, not only the code compiles correctly but the commas in the math environment can and should be removed too.