# Number all equations in align

Tags: equations, numbering, align

In the `align` environment you can put two (or more) equations on one line:

```
\begin{align}
x+y &= 1  &  x+z &= 1 \\
x+w &= 1  &  w+z &= 1
\end{align}
```

By default this results in two lines with equation numbers.  But there are 4 equations in the above example, and I would like to have them individually labeled and numbered.  Putting two labels on one line results in an error.

> How do you get equation numbers and labels for each separate equation in the `align` environment?

Alternative environments are OK, but because of the publisher this is expected to go to, I may not be able to add out of the ordinary packages.

I have tried side-by-side minipages with an `align` in each one, but then the equations are not aligned between columns and it looks terrible.

Comment: I believe this has already been asked. The problem is the ambiguity in the numbering: readers will have difficulties in attributing the number in the center of the page to either equation on the same row. And equation numbers should all be in a fixed position for ease of browsing.

Comment: If it has been asked, I haven't found the question.  Please provide a reference!

Comment: Related: [How to align a set of multiline equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations)

Comment: How should the numbering proceed: from left to right within a given row and from there on to the next row, or first all equations in the first column, followed by the equations in the second column?

Comment: It might be nice to control how numbering proceeds, but at least for the moment it does not matter.

Comment: The question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations is similar but not the same, and does not have an adequate answer: my equations vary in height and that technique results in misalignment on horizontal lines.

Comment: @JeffSnider - I suggest you post a new query, one that builds on the answer(s) provided in [Numbering side-by-side equations or inline equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35945/5001), and asks for specific assistance fixing the horizontal alignment of equations within a row if the equations vary in height and depth.