# How to label each equation in an align environment when there are multiple equations per line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, labels

I have a set of equations which in an aligned environment, with two equations per line. I want to give each equation its own unique label, something that looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a_{1} + a_{2} &= 0 \quad (A1), & a_{3} + a_{4} &= 0 \quad (A2) \\
b_{1} + b_{2} &= 0 \quad (A3), & b_{3} + b_{4} &= 0 \quad (A4) \\
c_{1} + c_{2} &= 0 \quad (A5), & c_{3} + c_{4} &= 0 \quad (A6)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would like to do this *without* manually assigning the labels A1, A2 etc at the end of each equation. So I was wondering if this is at all possible? Using the subequations environment allows you to give each *line* a label, but not each equation on each line. I should note that someone has already asked a similar question on the Latex website [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31577), however, the equations don't vertically align correctly using tabularx.

Comment: [Individual equations in multiple columns with individual numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239755/134144) seems to be related.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for providing the link, that answers my question. Neither a Google search or a stackexchange search brought it up.

Comment: Since you seem to be satisfied with the answer to the linked question, would you agree to close yours as a duplicate?

Comment: @leandriis I actually made a mistake, neither of the proposed solutions gives me the result that I was after.