# horizontal equations with numbering in left and centering

Tags: tables, equations, horizontal-alignment

I followed the code from [Numbering side-by-side equations or inline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35945/numbering-side-by-side-equations-or-inline-equations), got:

[image]

However, I desire for:

[image]
Meaning, the tabular is aligned to the left (or center), and numbering is **before** the equation, without a lot of space between the number and the equation.

How can I achieve this result?
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\section{Stackexchange Question}
The equations are:

\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
{\begin{align}
&\bar{U_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m U_{ij} \\
&\tilde{{U_{i}}} = \bar{{U_{i}}} + z_{\alpha \slash 2} \cdot \sigma_{U_{i}} 
\end{align}}
&
{\begin{align}
&\sigma_{foo}^2 = \sigma_{U_{i}}^2 = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m(U_{m}-\bar{U_{i}})^2 \\ 
&\tilde{y_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m v_{ij} \cdot U_{ij} + (1-v_{ij})\cdot L_{ij} 
\end{align}}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My humble opinion: why do you use a table? With the `enumitem` package you can create a columned numbered equations where there are no spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually not familiar with `enumitem`, and found the above as quick solution

Comment: Do you want a right-hand numbering for all equations in your document, or just for this group?

Comment: @EliSimhayev Excuse me, my was only a suggestion. All the best.

Comment: just for this group @Bernard
All my other equations are in vertical order

Comment: And the numbering should be columnwidse (I mean the numbers1 & 2 should be in the first column, not in the first row)?

Comment: @Bernard Hi, I saw before also the tasks package. I think that can be another alternative: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks-manual.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano: That's precisely what I was thinking of –  the  `shortlst` is still another possibility, but it's not in the official distributions for copyright reasons, and still another, Olga Lapko's `tablists`.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, I have understood but I did not know this situation. Anyway, I appreciated your work :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `tasks` package using manual enumeration  to have the same enumerate list of your image. Now it is perfect. :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tasks,amsmath,amssymb} 
\begin{document}
\section{Stackexchange Question}
The equations are:
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=(tsk[1]),label-width=4.5em, column-sep =4.4pt](2)
\task $\displaystyle \tilde{{U_{i}}} = \bar{{U_{i}}} + z_{\alpha \slash 2} \cdot \sigma_{U_{i}}$ 
\task[(3)] $\displaystyle \sigma_{\text{foo}}^2 = \sigma_{U_{i}}^2 = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m(U_{m}-\bar{U_{i}})^2$
\task[(2)] $\displaystyle \bar{U_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m U_{ij}$
\task[(4)] $\displaystyle \tilde{y_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m v_{ij} \cdot U_{ij} + (1-v_{ij})\cdot L_{ij}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A code with `tabularx` and `align`, using the `\leqnomode` command, defined in Werner's answer  to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193535/switch-between-leqno-and-reqno-options-of-amsmath-in-the-same-document). It uses the `equation` counter. The vertical spacing between the first & second line of align in the left column had to be found by trial and error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\section{Stackexchange Question}
The equations are:

{\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*2{>{\leqnomode\arraybackslash}X}}
{\begin{align}
& \bar{U_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m U_{ij} \\[1.6ex]
& \tilde{{U_{i}}} = \bar{{U_{i}}} + z_{\alpha \slash 2} \cdot \sigma_{U_{i}}
\end{align}}
&
{\begin{align}
& \sigma_{foo}^2 = \sigma_{U_{i}}^2 = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m(U_{m}-\bar{U_{i}})^2 \\
& \tilde{y_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m v_{ij} \cdot U_{ij} + (1-v_{ij}) \cdot L_{ij}
\end{align}}
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-10mm}
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{Stackexchange Question}
The equations are:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\arabic*)}]
\item $\bar{U_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m U_{ij}$
\item $\tilde{{U_{i}}} = \bar{{U_{i}}} + z_{\alpha \slash 2} \cdot 
 \sigma_{U_{i}} $ 
\columnbreak
\item $\sigma_{foo}^2 = \sigma_{U_{i}}^2 = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{j=1}^m(U_{m}- 
\bar{U_{i}})^2$
\item $\tilde{y_i} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m v_{ij} \cdot U_{ij} + (1- 
v_{ij})\cdot L_{ij}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In the enumerate list there are the rounded brackets in the image of the user.

Comment: Very good :-) +1